# Need name of a classic Sci Fi episode, involving a soldier frozen in time saving a woman?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I'm looking for the name of a tv episode about a soldier who somehow is the only one that is NOT frozen in time.  He has a dilemma of saving everyone (I think) or saving his wife, who will have a car accident once time starts again.  He ends up rigging a truck that will somehow save his wife so that he can "fix" whatever the problem is and time re-starts.

I remember that it was in black and white and I **thought** it was the Twilight Zone but can't find it.  Maybe The Outer Limits?

Comment: I read the title as "...involving a soldier frozen in a time-saving woman".  Sounded intriguing. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like an episode of **The Outer Limits** original 1965 run, ***The Premonition*** (Season 2 episode 16). Instead of a soldier, he's a Test Pilot, saving his daughter, not his wife (she's with him), and it's from a military truck, not a car. Semantics.

[From Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Premonition_(The_Outer_Limits)):

> Jim Darcy, the pilot of an X-15 rocket-powered research aircraft, and his wife, Linda, become trapped 10 seconds ahead of their time, enabling them to watch time unfold to catch up with them at the rate of about one second every 30 minutes. In the time left before returning to synch with normal time, they see that their daughter, Janie, is about to be hit by a rolling military truck whose parking brake had not been set. Jim and Linda's inability to move objects in the "real" world prevents them from resetting the truck's parking brake or pulling young Janie out of danger. Their problem is aggravated as they soon learn that at the moment when time "catches up" with them, they must assume the exact positions they had been in five hours earlier, when this whole thing started, or they could remain in that state forever.

Comment: Yes, that's the one!  I was pretty young when I watched it years ago so I'm not at all surprised I got several things wrong.  Thank you so much for answering my question, it was bugging me like crazy!

Answer (score 6):

Echoing my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73631/movie-about-a-man-and-a-woman-accelerated-in-time-the-rest-of-the-world-was-sus/73632#73632) on another stack, This is an episode of 'The Outer Limits' called ["The Premonition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Premonition_%28The_Outer_Limits%29) from January 1965.

**Per wikipedia**

> Jim Darcy, the pilot of an X-15 rocket-powered research aircraft, and
>   his wife, Linda, become trapped 10 seconds ahead of their time,
>   enabling them to watch time unfold to catch up with them at the rate
>   of about one second every 30 minutes. In the time left before
>   returning to synch with normal time, they see that their daughter,
>   Janie, is about to be hit by a rolling military truck whose parking
>   brake had not been set. **Jim and Linda's inability to move objects in
>   the "real" world prevents them from resetting the truck's parking
>   brake or pulling young Janie out of danger.** Their problem is
>   aggravated as they soon learn that at the moment when time "catches
>   up" with them, they must assume the exact positions they had been in
>   five hours earlier, when this whole thing started, or they could
>   remain in that state forever.

> **Jim hits upon a way to save his daughter from death. He removes seatbelts from his wife's car and ties them to the back wheel of the menacing truck. He then ties the other end around the brake lever** so that the truck's brakes will engage the moment the time warp ends. (It was, by that time, moving at 10 mph.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the mechanism used to stop the truck. I didn't see the episode, and probably won't any time soon, but the other answer left me wanting to know!  (I proposed an edit to add a spoiler block, though.)